# What types of sites can be hosted on Linux Hosting servers?

Tags: php, asp.net, linux, web-hosting

I would like to know whether I can host ASP.NET site on a Linux Hosting server?
Or is it that only PHP and HTML sites can be hosted on such a server?

I am ignorant.

Please guide me.

Comment: only good websites, bad one should be hosted on a windows server!

Comment: read this maby it will help you: http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can run Mono on an Apache server.
[www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2):

Any type of site could theoretically be hosted on a server. It just depends on what software is installed on that server, that supports Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to host ASP.NET, I would recommend you to find Windows hosting provider. Please check hostforlife.eu, they support ASP.NET, PHP and also HTML. I find it from Microsoft site. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

you can host [ASP.net](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET) on Apache server.

If you are hosting the ASP.NET site in the [windows(IIS)](http://hioxindia.com/windows-hosting.php) server all the version will be supported and there will be many applications that can be supported. But in linux server there will be only specific versions and there are less applications.